# Mysqli Get Entire Row

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

```
#Do a database query and return all rows of GET ID  
$result=$mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE product-id = '$id'");

    while($row=$result->fetch_array())
    {
        $id             =     $row['product-id'];
        $pagename       =     $row['product-name'];
        $description    =     $row['product-description'];
        $samples        =     $row['product-sample-designs'];
    }


# free result set
mysqli_free_result($result);
}

#close connection
mysqli_close($mysqli);
```

If i remove `WHERE product-id = '$id'` # Result is no errors and first row is displayed.

As the code shows I get this error: "Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_array() on a non-object"

I'm just trying to get all the data in a row where my GET id = the TABLE `product-id`. This process is much easier in MYSQL. Im new to this OOP style and I find it confusing. An explanation is greatly appreciated. ~THANKS!

Comment: I'm popping the PDO cherry. Use PDO, or at least bind your parameters sir! Other than the usual safety guards, it's a lot faster for the db to process a prepared statement :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the column name contains hyphens, you need to enclose it by back-ticks.

```
$result=$mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE `product-id` = '$id'");
```

But it is not a good idea of using hyphens in column/table names, use underscore `_` would be better.

Comment: yes!! that works I will accept as soon as SO let's me. That issue has plagued me for the past 20 minutes! THANK YOU

Comment: Not related to injection issues. You don't need to use back-ticks to enclose the names if you use `_`.